# What does "Back up" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Fight Club (1999)*, Narrator hugs Bob, who is victim of testicular cancer:

> Bob: OK, you cry now.
>
> Narrator: No, wait. **Back up**. Let me start earlier. For six months, I
> couldn't  sleep. I couldn't sleep...with insomnia, nothing's real.

What does "Back up" mean in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say *back up* when you want to pause a conversation and return to something that was just said.

> [back up](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/back+up)
> 4. verb To return to an item previously mentioned.
> *Whoa, back up—Janet and Jim are getting married?*
> (TFD)

I'm guessing that the narrator is about to explain why he won't cry. Or maybe he wants to divert Bob's attention and avoid crying.